# How to configure svn authz on Windows?

Tags: windows, svn, configuration, authz

We would like to start two new development projects: `Project1` and `Project2`. We have two groups of developers:

- `GroupA` should have full (read + write) access to both projects, and
- `GroupB` should have no access to `Project1`, but full access to `Project2`.

I followed [Jeff Atwood's tutorial](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html) and successfully installed [subversion 1.7.6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/) on Windows Server 2003 as a Windows service. I tested the system by adding folders and files, and commiting changes, and everything worked as it should (the client was [TortoiseSVN 1.7.9](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/?source=dlp)).

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how I could configure the access rights of our developer groups in `authz`. The developers can connect to the server, but get `Authorization failed` messages when try to commit something.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: The question is answered in http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

Did you try VisualSVN Server? It provides neat UI to manage authorization settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advise you to read the [SVNBook (Version Control with Subversion)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/). Please see the chapter which describes [the path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html). I think that the chapter answers your question.

The sample `authz` file is provided below. Please note that I don't explicitly set *'no access'* rule for **GroupB** on `/repo/Project1` repository directory. I set *'no access'* to the root node for *'everyone'* and then this permission gets inherited by it's child items unless you explicitly provide access to a folder or a file.

```
[/]
*=

[groups]
GroupA=john,sally
GroupB=harry,george

[repo:/Project1]
@GroupA=rw

[repo:/Project2]
@GroupA=rw
@GroupB=rw
```

I'd like to note that you can drastically simplify the process of managing SVN user permissions if you use [VisualSVN Server Manager](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/#console).

*It provides comfortable UI to manage user permissions which you can find really helpful:*[image: VisualSVN Server Manager]

### Update 2016

To manage access rules for SVN repositories hosted on VisualSVN Server you can now use PowerShell cmdlets packaged with VisualSVN Server. Beginning with version 3.4, VisualSVN Server includes PowerShell module that should help you with this task. The cmdlets you are looking for are

- [`Add-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Add-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Get-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Select-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Select-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Set-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Set-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Remove-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Remove-SvnAccessRule)

Read the article [KB88: VisualSVN Server PowerShell Cmdlet Reference](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/) for the complete list of VisualSVN Server PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: Thank you! VisualSVN Server rocks :)

Comment: Awesome never knew about this tool!